# Is the ceiling in hell supposed to be that low?

Tags: terraria

So, I was playing Terraria, just created a new character for 1.3 because my old character was a bit cheated and I didn't have fun with it, couple hours after, I make a Hellevator, then notice that the ceiling is really low, or the lava is really high, so here is my question, is that a new feature in 1.3 or is it just an unlucky generation ? How am I suppose to fight the wall of flesh like that ? Btw, my world size is Large.

[image]

Comment: You may have misremembered. The clearing between lava and ceiling looks normal, as it has been since at least 1.1 (when I first started playing)

Comment: I'd say it's easier in a smaller corridor to fight the wall of flesh as you can more easily do tripple damage as you can more easily hit all three parts of it.

Comment: Looks ordinary, just make a long platform that stretches across the "underworld" and goes through buildings so that the ceiling doesn't even matter..

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know and can find, there haven't been any changes to Underworld (Hell) generation in 1.3 or since (or even before for that matter). There aren't any changes listed in the [1.3 changelog](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/1.3.0.1) or [Underworld wiki page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Underworld). (There's new music though.)

To me, your Underworld ceiling looks maybe a bit low, but nothing out of the ordinary, and the lava seems normal. I find that parts of the ceiling often is touching the buildings (Ruined Houses, to be exact). I'd say it's just some unlucky random generation that made it out a bit cramped like that.

As for fighting the Wall of Flesh, you can always level some sections of the Underworld to make it easier to fight (make flat platforms, etc.). Hopefully there are some suitable areas in your Underworld for that.